# Target .net 4.5 but deploy to .net 4.0 is it possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

I have to work under the following policy "all software must be 1 version behind", I don't particularly like this and I cant change it.  so that would mean that our production machine will only go as far as .NET 4.0 for now, only when .NET 5 is release can we move to 4.5! silly, I know.

so currently I am planning on proposing for dev machines to upgrade to Visual studio 2012 and target .NET 4.0 which is ok for now;

We have some projects in the immediate future which would need a lot of asynchronous programming and I want to be able to use all the 4.5 syntactic goodness the async/await and all the rest of the improvements.

so what are the options! accept "thats just life" and only target 4.0 and moan! or is there a way to target 4.5 in dev and import some 4.5 dll's into prod, is this even possible? ultimately is it possible to develop to take advantage of the 4.5 features in any way and deploy to 4.0? any advice please...

Comment: Semi offtopic, but: I know you hate this but it's very standard for large organizations and to be honest not that bad a process (has saved our bacon a number of times - finance industry)

Comment: @Michael Agreed. Most Large Organizations, especially in the financial or education industry but in many others, have very old versions of things and are reluctant - if not worse - to upgrade.

Comment: +1 nice question, and I learned something new from the accepted answer.  Congrats on reaching 500 points.

Comment: If the policy allows ServicePacks to be installed then I would argue that .Net 4 and 4.5 are same major version with 4.5 being only a patch on 4 with 100% backward compatibility http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2011/09/26/compatibility-of-net-framework-4-5.aspx

Comment: Bosses don't understand that developers likes new frameworks. Sad.

Comment: I guess you could target 4.5 now that it is now 3 versions behind the latest (4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6)

Comment: This becomes a non issue with .netCore, we can now package what ever version with the app

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're looking for [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/).

Comment: make sure you test your app on XP if your app is supported on XP.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the [link for reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.

Comment: @Kev: If that link braks, the answer will become useless anyway.

Comment: UPDATE: "The owner has unlisted this package. This could mean that the package is deprecated or shouldn't be used anymore."

Answer (score 7):

Note that it's not supported to create .NET4.5 app and then attempt to re-target it for .NET4.0. Basically, when you build app with .NET4.5, you may be using new APIs that got added in 4.5 and are not present in 4.0. So your app will not work correctly.

Comment: Everyone knew it was impossible. Then came along a fool who didn’t know it, and he did it.